# SQL Server Maintenance plan that goes to next step when the condition passes

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plans

I am trying to create a maintenance plan in SQL Server. What I want to do is I have an Execute T-SQL Task and inside the task I have condition below:

```
Use master
go
DECLARE @dbname varchar(1000)
set @dbname = 'myTEstDB'
If sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica ( @dbname ) = 1   
 BEGIN
 END
```

If the If condition brings 1 I want the maintenance plan to go to next step.
Can we do this? Please let me know if there is a way to implement it like this.

Comment: What are you doing in your maintenance plan? This could be step 1 in an agent job which continues to the next job on success and quits the job on failure. In step 2 - n you'd have what ever maintenance steps you want (back up, index, etc) via Ola's scripts or custom scripts.

Comment: user3325655 if you are making scripts for maintenance and @scsimon's mention of Ola does not mean anything to you, you should look at   https://ola.hallengren.com/ solutions to all your problems are probably there.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you got to refer [Ola Hallengren's](https://ola.hallengren.com)  maintenance solution.

However, following conditional script might be helpful for any other purpose that need consider only primary replica:

```
Declare @is_DB_HADREnabled bit;
Declare @isPrimaryReplica bit;
Declare @Databasename varchar (120) = DB_NAME();


select @is_DB_HADREnabled = IIF(group_database_id IS NULL, 0,1) from sys.databases where [name] = @DatabaseName;

        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (select db.name
                        from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states as hadr
                            join sys.databases as db on hadr.group_database_id = db.group_database_id
                        where is_local = 1 and is_primary_replica = 1 and db.name = @DatabaseName
                        )
                SET @isPrimaryReplica = 1 
            ELSE 
                SET @isPrimaryReplica = 0 
        END


    IF @is_DB_HADREnabled = 0 or @isPrimaryReplica = 1

        BEGIN 
            Print 'This block able to run on only Primary replica when a database part of AG. Also, run for the databases which are not part of AG'
        END 

        ELSE 
        PRINT 'This has to be either Primary replica of DATABASE or DATABASE must not be part of any AG'
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This is a workaround suggesting to use Ola stuff instead of built-in functionality.